# What free icons fonts are available?

Tags: css, fonts, icon

With the possibility to embed fonts in websites using @font-face CSS, some creative webdesigners developed their way to display icons using fonts, instead of images.

But most of the available icon fonts (or "font-face" kits) are paid, such as:

- [Pictos](http://pictos.drewwilson.com/)
- [Fico](http://fico.lensco.be/)
- [Tipogram](http://tipogram.com/)
- [KDN Media](http://kdnmedia.com/)
- [IconMoon](http://keyamoon.com/icomoon/) *free version, with less icons

So, what free icons pack in font format do you know?

*Please limit one "font-face" kit per answer - and include why you enjoy/recommend it.*

**Edit:**

This question can be converted into a community wiki, if the moderators want, because there is no best answer, and each response is welcome as a knowledge that can be enjoyed by many.

Comment: This is really cool, never seen this before. Hope there will be some nice answers.

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question does not meet the criteria set forth in the [faq]

Comment: Why my question is closed? :(

In a polite manner, I understand that there is great interest from the community for this question.

Answer (score 2):

PJ Onori's [Iconic](http://somerandomdude.com/work/iconic/) set is licensed under Creative Commons.

Comment: Thanks, Su'! Excellent set!

I hope this question will be reopened soon, and we'll all benefit from the answers like yours!